# how to build 【openSSL-1.0.2u】 for Android,and if possible, how to merge Android Makefile?

Tags: linux, android-ndk, openssl, android.mk

when I  use 1.1.1d 's build script, encounter some trouble, and how to generate kind of platorm, such as armv8a,armeabi, armv7a,x86..and so on

Comment: Please further explain your Problem. Try to give the people here as much information as possible so they will be able to help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Makefile file to achieve your goal, the file's name is `Makefile.shared`, look the point at `link_o.gnu goal;`

Notice The file is auto generated by make, it doesn't existed by default!